# RESTful Routing - Cannot Get my 'NEW' route to post (JavaScript, Node, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am stuck and frustrated. Hoping someone can help me out. Can someone tell me why my new POST route is not working?

*I am trying to create a notes archive wherein each category has a different schema, all within an rNotes subdirectory under the views directory*

Here is the folder structure..

- jp_Res_Notes
- ```
    node_modules
  ```
- ```
        views
  ```
- ```
          rNotes
  ```

- ```
              tRex
  ```
- ```
                tRex.ejs
  ```
- ```
                new.ejs
  ```

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require ("express"),
     app = express(),
     bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var tRex = [
        {name: "Big Girl", image:"https://images.unsplash.com/pxxxx", pms:"Dr Grant", cage:"North", price:".089", lease:"yes", weights:"+/-20",  process:"aggressive! These guys know their stuff" },
        {name: "Big Boy", image:"https://images.unsplash.com/pxxxx", pms:"L Dern", cage:"South", price:"1.5", lease:"yes", weights:"+/-10",  process:"Hungry" },
        {name: "Brother", image:"https://images.unsplash.com/XXX", pms:"Timmy", cage:"South", price:"1.5", lease:"yes", weights:"+/-10",  process:"Thirsty" },
    ]

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/rNotes/tRex/tRex", function(req,res){
    res.render("rNotes/tRex/tRex",{tRex:tRex});
});

app.post("/rNotes/tRex/tRex", function(req,res){
    
    var name =              req.body.name;
    var image =             req.body.image;
    var pms =               req.body.pms;
    var cage =              req.body.cage;
    var price =             req.body.price;
    var lease =             req.body.lease;
    var weights =           req.body.weights;
    var process =           req.body.process;
    var newtRex = {name: name, image:image, pms:pms, cage:cage,                                                                                
                   price:price,lease:lease,weights:weights,process:process}
    tRex.push(newtRex);
    res.redirect("rNotes/tRex/tRex");
});

app.get("rNotes/tRex/tRex/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("/rNotes/tRex/new.ejs");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT||3000, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("The Jurassic Park Notes has started!!");
});
```

Here is my new.ejs file

```
<%- include("../partials/header") %>

<h1>
    New T Rex!
</h1>

<form action="/rNotes/tRex/tRex" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"               placeholder="tRex Name">
    <input type="text" name="image"              placeholder="image url">
    <input type="text" name="pms"                placeholder="pms">
    <input type="text" name="cage"               placeholder="cage">
    <input type="text" name="price"              placeholder="price">
    <input type="text" name="lease"              placeholder="yes or no?">
    <input type="text" name="weights"            placeholder="weights">
    <input type="text" name="process"            placeholder="process">
    <button>Submit!</button>
```

Here is my tRex.ejs file

```
<%- include("../partials/header") %>

<h1>This is the T Rex page! And.. its not working!!</h1>

<% tRex.forEach(function(tRex){ %>
    <div>
        <h4><%= tRex.name %></h4>
        <img src="<%= tRex.image %>">
        <li><%= tRex.pms %></li>    
        <li><%= tRex.cage %></li>
        <li><%= tRex.price %></li>  
        <li><%= tRex.lease %></li>
        <li><%= tRex.weights %></li>    
        <li><%= tRex.process %></li>
    </div>
                                      
<% }); %>
```

I know something is off with my post routes. I think it has something to do with the use of subfolders but I would really appreciate someone offering me some guidance.

I get this error

### **Cannot GET /rNotes/tRex/rNotes/tRex/tRex**

Please help!

Comment: `res.redirect("rNotes/tRex/tRex");` — You forgot the `/` at the front of the path making it **relative** to `app.post("/rNotes/tRex/tRex"`

Comment: now I get CANNOT POST /rNotes/tRex/tRex/rNotes/tRex/tRex